# Can I use dplyr mutate() or ifelse statements to make a conditional time since diagnosis variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a "time since diagnosis" variable that is conditional on two other existing variables in my data.

Here is some example data:

```
id <- c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0002", "0002", "0002", "0003", "0003", "0003", "0003")
dementia <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
age_visit <- c("80", "81", "82","50", "51", "52","60", "61", "62", "63")
ds <- data.frame(id, dementia, age_visit)
```

I have a binary diagnosis variable `dementia` in a long format data set.
Looks like this:

```
    id     dementia   age_visit
1 0001        0        80
2 0001        0        81
3 0001        1        82
4 0002        0        50
5 0002        1        51
6 0002        1        52
7 0003        0        60
8 0003        1        61
9 0003        0        62
```

I want an `age_at_diagnosis` variable that pastes the `age_visit` for the first instance of the dementia diagnosis, when it first equals 1. This step isn't vital if there is a way to simply skip to the last step which is the time since the first instance of diagnosis. The main problem is that individuals can be diagnosed then have another assessment that is null. I want the first case and then the time since that first assessment to be the time since diagnosis.

So the end result would look like this, with `time_sincedx` being `age_visit - age_at_dx`:

```
     id   dementia    age_visit   age_at_dx    time_sincedx
1  0001        0        80        NA           NA
2  0001        0        81        NA           NA
3  0001        1        82        82            0
4  0002        0        50        NA           NA
5  0002        1        51        51            0
6  0002        1        52        51            1
7  0003        0        60        NA           NA
8  0003        1        61        61            0
9  0003        0        62        61            1
10 0003        1        63        61            2
```

Is there any way to do this with dplyr?
I've tried this but it's not quite right. It pastes each age at each occasion leaving me with zero's down the `time_since_dx` column.

```
df <- mutate(df, age_at_dx = ifelse(dementia==1, age_at_visit, NA))
df$time_sincedx<- df$age_at_visit - df$age_atdx
```

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little subsetting and `tidyr::fill` to deal with excess `NA` values will get you there:

```
library(tidyverse)

ds %>% group_by(id) %>%    # evaluate patients individually
    mutate(age_visit = as.integer(as.character(age_visit)),    # factor to integer
           # if no dementia, NA else min age where dementia == 1
           age_at_dx = ifelse(dementia == 0, NA, min(age_visit[dementia == 1]))) %>% 
    fill(age_at_dx) %>%    # fill in NAs after non-NA (where dx == 1, then 0 like line 9)
    mutate(time_since_dx = age_visit - age_at_dx)

## Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
## Groups: id [3]
## 
##        id dementia age_visit age_at_dx time_since_dx
##    <fctr>    <dbl>     <int>     <int>         <int>
## 1    0001        0        80        NA            NA
## 2    0001        0        81        NA            NA
## 3    0001        1        82        82             0
## 4    0002        0        50        NA            NA
## 5    0002        1        51        51             0
## 6    0002        1        52        51             1
## 7    0003        0        60        NA            NA
## 8    0003        1        61        61             0
## 9    0003        0        62        61             1
## 10   0003        1        63        61             2
```

or to skip the `age_at_dx` column,

```
ds %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(age_visit = as.integer(as.character(age_visit)), 
           time_since_dx = age_visit - min(age_visit[dementia == 1]), 
           time_since_dx = ifelse(time_since_dx < 0, NA, time_since_dx))    # make negatives NA

## Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
## Groups: id [3]
## 
##        id dementia age_visit time_since_dx
##    <fctr>    <dbl>     <int>         <int>
## 1    0001        0        80            NA
## 2    0001        0        81            NA
## 3    0001        1        82             0
## 4    0002        0        50            NA
## 5    0002        1        51             0
## 6    0002        1        52             1
## 7    0003        0        60            NA
## 8    0003        1        61             0
## 9    0003        0        62             1
## 10   0003        1        63             2
```

Comment: If `age_visit` is not in a sequence, `time_since_dx` will not come out as a sequence of numbers. If the last visit of 0003 is at age 65, rather than 63, time_since_dx will be 4. What would you do?

Comment: @jazzurro According to the question, `time_since_dx` should be `age_visit - age_at_dx`, which would be elapsed time, not number of visits, so 4 would be correct.

Comment: I see. I interpreted `time` as the number of records since the first time of dementia record, not actual physical time. The OP got two options now. So whichever she meant, she knows what to do. :)

Comment: @alistaire Great! That min() addition looks like it is exactly what I was looking for. Trying to implement it now but I am getting: `Error: incompatible types, expecting a integer vector` message. All of the relevant variables are listed as integer when I check using `class()`.

Comment: @JamieKnight Hm, I can't reproduce that particular error. If you add piece by piece, can you tell what function is raising it?

Comment: @alistaire, It may be a bug that I found here https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/958 where the ifelse is causing the NA's to be returned as logical instead of numeric. Maybe an update will fix. updating now...

Comment: @JamieKnight You can specify `NA_integer_` if you like. Generally `dplyr::if_else` cares about that level of type-safety while `base::ifelse` doesn't, though, which is why it's an odd error.

Comment: fixed! I had version 3.1, updated to 3.3 - and now it works no problem. Thank you for the great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way for you. First, I converted `age_visit` to integer. Then, I grouped the data by `id`. I created `age_at_dx` using indices for a logical check. I identified the first row (row number) that dementia == 1 appeared using `which()`. Any row number smaller than that row number should be NA. The rest of rows should have the number in the identified row. This logic was used to created `age_at_dx`. Then, I created `time_sincedx` using another logical check. In this case, I checked if each element of `age_at_dx` is NA or not. If an element is not an NA, I created index numbers with `cumsum()` in `time_sincedx`. Otherwise, I created NA in `time_sincedx`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(ds, age_visit = as.integer(as.character(age_visit))) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(age_at_dx = if_else(row_number() < which(dementia == 1)[1],
                           NA_integer_, age_visit[dementia == 1][1]),
       time_sincedx = if_else(!is.na(age_at_dx), cumsum(!is.na(age_at_dx))-1, NA_real_))


#       id dementia age_visit age_at_dx time_sincedx
#   <fctr>    <dbl>     <int>     <int>        <dbl>
#1    0001        0        80        NA           NA
#2    0001        0        81        NA           NA
#3    0001        1        82        82            0
#4    0002        0        50        NA           NA
#5    0002        1        51        51            0
#6    0002        1        52        51            1
#7    0003        0        60        NA           NA
#8    0003        1        61        61            0
#9    0003        0        62        61            1
#10   0003        1        63        61            2
```

Comment: thanks for this alternate code option. I am getting the same error I got for the above code on this one as well, any ideas?

Comment: @JamieKnight It seems that you fixed the problem seeing your other comments. Are you doing alright?

Comment: yes  thank you. All the solutions work fine now since I updated.

Comment: @JamieKnight I am glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

no fancy tricks in this solution: just a couple of transparent applications of split, apply, combine methods.

The first step is ensuring that the data set you received is arranged properly to later allow for processing in the missed diagnosis years. 
Then we essentially fill down the years that are missing: checking for null diagnoses which lag a previous year's positive diagnosis. The logic works out that for where there is a Null diagnosis for that year AND a positive diagnosis for the same patient ID in the preceding visit year, commute that positive diagnosis value down in the dementiaCorr column. Caveat on this logic is that it can cover only single year gaps: note - am very curious to investigate tidyr::fill()'s capabilities [btw: thank you, @alistaire for helping me discover this!]

Then, After filling in diagnosis gaps we can group by and collect the minimum year of diagnosis. After that we tie the data back into the complete listing, calculate the durations as directed and select/order the data frame as desired for final expression.

```
df <- 
    ds %>% 
    arrange(id, age_visit) %>% 
    mutate(dementiaCorr = ifelse((lag(id)==id)&lag(dementia == 1)|dementia == 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(dementiaCorr == 1) %>% 
    mutate(age_at_dx = min(as.integer(age_visit))) %>%
    select(-dementia) %>% 
    right_join(ds, by = c('id', 'age_visit')) %>% 
    mutate(time_sincedx = as.integer(age_visit)-as.integer(age_at_dx)) %>% 
    select(id, dementia, age_visit, age_at_dx, time_sincedx)
```

Alternatively you can just switch the operations around and process the data in a sequence that more closely matches the progression of the data development that you had walked us through in your question.

In this approach we again start by ensuring that the data is arranged correctly for filling in the gaps. Then we group and select out the mininum age of diagnosis. After trimming it down and then joining that back onto the original dataset, we remove the duplicates that arise due to the ambiguous diagnosis values that occur in the dataset.
Then we fill in the gaps: Caveat is as before 1 year gap unless you re-perform gap fill.
Finally the elapsed time since first diagnosis is calculated from integer converted values and then the chosen columns are order/selected.

```
df <- 
    ds %>% 
    arrange(id, age_visit) %>% 
    filter(dementia == 1) %>% 
    mutate(minageofDx = age_visit) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(agedxPrep = min(minageofDx)) %>% 
    select(id, dementia, agedxPrep) %>%
    right_join(ds) %>% ungroup %>% distinct %>% 
    mutate(age_at_dx = ifelse(is.na(agedxPrep) & (lag(id)==id) & lag(dementia == 1), # Conditional
                              lag(agedxPrep), agedxPrep), # trueVal, falseVal 
           time_sincedx = as.integer(age_visit)-as.integer(age_at_dx)) %>% 
    select(id, dementia, age_visit, age_at_dx, time_sincedx)
```

Hope either of these simple, straightforward methods with their open, flat logic perhaps prove more helpful to you than the nested and intricate code of the more advanced programming styles.

Comment: thanks for this alternate solution. I notice you said `Caveat on this logic is that it can cover only single year gaps`. There are a few occasions where I have more than a few year gap. I will have to check in more detail about how this is being handled in the other solutions as well - thanks for bringing that up.